# VPN doesn't have access to drives unless I use the default gateway

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn, gateway

I am trying to setup a VPN connection on one of our office servers so that many of our employees can access our drives when out of town or for important business meetings. However I have a weird glitch in where if the default gateway option is checked they can see the drives and files, but get no internet access. If I have the default gateway option unchecked then they have there internet and can successfully connect to the VPN, but they are not able to see any of the drives or files.

The server is running Windows Server 2003 Standard while the employees run either XP or 7 Professional.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

The VPN setup is PPTP and the main server is behind a SonicWall if that is of any importance.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have a routing issue.  You may need to push a route to your VPN clients for you internal network.  Update your question with details about what type of VPN you are using, and someone may be able to point you at docs about pushing a route to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Definately a routing issue. Most VPN clients push a route automatically, so I bet you have overlapping netblocks. Please provide the following:

Network/subnet mask/default gateway of your remote network and office network. Should look something like 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1. Also, provide the routing table of one of the remote stations when it's connected to the VPN ("route print" from the command prompt).